# How to use .contains with array?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have an array in a document that contains a list of user ids.
I'd like to find all documents that have this list of user ids.

I know I can do something like:

```
r.db('unicorn')
  .table('rooms').filter(function(doc){
    return doc('people').contains(
      "id-one","id-two"
      )
  })
```

I know this will work great, but I have to hardcode things. How do I pass the `contains` function an array of values to match against?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a little digging, The simplest solution was to use [args](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/args/). Was a bit non-obvious from the examples. This way I can pass in dynamic values and run commands with them.

```
r.db('unicorn')
  .table('rooms').filter(function(doc){
    return doc('people').contains(
      r.args(["id-one","id-two"]) 
      )
  })
```

Comment: Thx a lot u rocks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setIntersection](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/set_intersection/) and pass array:

```
r.db('unicorn')
  .table('rooms').filter(function(doc){
      return doc('people').default([]).setIntersection(
         ["id-one","id-two"]
      ).count().eq(2)
  })
```

So, if you have array:

```
var myArr =  ["id-one","id-two"];
```

You can write query like this:

```
r.db('unicorn')
  .table('rooms').filter(function(doc){
      return doc('people').default([]).setIntersection(myArr).count().eq(myArr.length)
  })
```

Comment: That's a very nifty way of approaching that problem :D. Was trying something very similar, until i landed on r.args.